# Icons not found on azure

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am installing your fonts on my server of Azure and I am having problems displaying the icons.

The css I use I took it as a cue from a template with bootstrap

In local font works correctly but when I upload pages to the server do not display the icons, so I think it's a problem on the server side.

Searching the net I added to my web.config this piece of code

```
             <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
         <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
         <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
     </staticContent>
```

and I removed the 404 error telling me that the font was not found
but I can not display anything

I also tried moving the files in the same folder as the css or root, but nothing to do

[Here you can see the site](http://www.servexia.com/)

colored squares in the center of the site should get out your icons.

the problem appears with explorer, chrome and firefox

I thank you in advance and I congratulate you for the excellent work.

Comment: If i look at the coloured squares they do have an i tag - but the class is blank e.g. <i class=""></i> . However the fontawsoem tage in the footer (rocket, cubes etc) are working fine.  have you examined the produced pages in the browser to see what is occurring ?

Comment: Thank you in updating the database I had loaded the data and I had not noticed the absence of the class